# Factory pattern in Typescript and expose only Factory Class

Tags: java, node.js, typescript, factory

I'm developing a node module in typescript using factory pattern where I want to expose only factory class and interface.

Structure:

iexp.ts

```
export interface IExp { 
    methodX(); 
}
```

A.ts

```
class A implements IExp {
}
```

B.ts

```
class B implements IExp {
}
```

factory.ts

```
export class ExpFactory {
    createInstance(type:string) : IExp{
      if(type=="A") return new A();
      else return new B();
    }
}
```

All classes and interface are in their own source file. I do not want to expose class A and class B, so I did not use **export** but then I'm not able to use them in ExpFactory class either. In Java, classes can have package scope, but how can I do same thing in typescript?

Comment: If you want to have these classes in separate files then each one has to be exported.  There's no equivalent to the package access modifier in typescript. What you can do is to import all of those classes into a single module which then only exports what you want, and then import that module and use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `A` and `B` from `ExpFactory` if they're in the same file. If not, then you must export them from the module, which is all or nothing (it can only be public).

However, that doesn't make them easily accessible from outside your module. If you're bundling your library, the entry point will have to export the classes again, or they won't be accessible outside your module. If you aren't bundling, users would have to figure out the relative path and import directly from that.

Comment: How do I export the classes again? I want to organize my code into sub-folder. Let's say I put all the class files into MyModule/Code/ folder. And I have an another .ts file where I have imported and exported Factory and Interface. Now I pack my node module with this new ts file as main file. How do I access these exported Factory and interface? It still requires me to write full relative path to Code folder.

Answer (score 0):

(Personal style advice) In javascript, factory pattern is better achieved by using closures and option bags.

```
class Root {
  method1()
  method2()
}

class Child extends Root {
  method1() //...
}
```

is better achieved by something like

```
function Root( opts : Options ) {
   var method1 = opts.method1 || defaultMethod1()
   var method2 = opts.method2 || defaultMethod2()
   return { method1, method2 }
}
```

The use of `new` is completely unnecessary in javascript, if not even considered harmful.